# Как сделать кнопки меняющие цвет?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Всем здравствуйте, я хочу создать 3 кнопки, что бы при наведении они поднимались, а потом при нажатии меняли свой цвет, но, каждая по отдельности и сохраняла цвет пока снова не нажму, что бы она стала как обычно, языки использую JS, CSS, HTML

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Прошу

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll("button")
btns.forEach(btn=>{
    btn.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        btn.classList.toggle("red")
    })
})
```

```css
.red {
    background-color: red;
}

button {
    transition: .5s;
}

button:hover {
    transform: translateY(-2px);
}
```

```html
<button>Кнопка</button>
    <button>Кнопка</button>
    <button>Кнопка</button>
```